# How to compare two arrays and remove matching elements from one for the next loop?

Tags: php, arrays

How else might you compare two arrays ($A and $B )and reduce matching elements out of the first to prep for the next loop over the array $A?

```
$A = array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8);
$B = array(1,2,3,4);

$C = array_intersect($A,$B);  //equals (1,2,3,4)
$A = array_diff($A,$B);       //equals (5,6,7,8)
```

Is this the simplest way or is there a way to use another function that I haven't thought of?  My goal is to have an array that I can loop over, pulling out groups of related content (I have defined those relationships elsewhere) until the array returns false.

Comment: It could be me, but I don't think the question is very clear. As I read it you are just interested in array_diff($A,$B) (which seems pretty simple). Or is the calculation of $C also essential? (If so, you can use array_diff($A,$C) instead of array_diff($A,$B).)

Comment: No, I am declaring $C to be the intersection of $A and $B

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You've got it. Just use `array_diff` or `array_intersect`. Doesn't get much easier than that.

**Edit:**
For example:

```
$arr_1 = array_diff($arr_1, $arr_2);
$arr_2 = array_diff($arr_2, $arr_1);
```

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8691348/2210140)

Comment: Also consider [array_diff_assoc](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff-assoc.php) if the order of the values in the two arrays is important.

Answer (score 6):

Dear easy and clean way

```
$clean1 = array_diff($array1, $array2); 
$clean2 = array_diff($array2, $array1); 
$final_output = array_merge($clean1, $clean2);
```

Comment: This answer is better, as it re-arrange the array elements on matching indexes. Unlike stuart's answer, which will remove elements from the matching indexes. So if there was a matching element at index 1, you try to access index 1 in result array, it will throw error.

Comment: I don't know who stuart is, but asker's requirements do not mention any interest in respecting the indexes of the arrays.  This answer is doing the same thing as rg88's answer and then calls `array_merge()` for some unknown reason.

Answer (score 2):

See also [array_unique](http://us.php.net/array_unique). If you concatenate the two arrays, it will then yank all duplicates.

Comment: I don't see how this answers the question or offers the required output.

Answer (score 0):

Hey, even better solution: [array _ uintersect.](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.array-uintersect.php)
This let's you compare the arrays as per array_intersect but then it lets you compare the data with a callback function.

Comment: What benefit does `array_uintersect()` bring?  I don't see it offering any value for this task.

Answer (score -1):

Try to this

```
$a = array(0=>'a',1=>'x',2=>'c',3=>'y',4=>'w');
$b = array(1=>'a',6=>'b',2=>'y',3=>'z');
$c = array_intersect($a, $b);

$result = array_diff($a, $c);
print_r($result);
```