# How to filter array and create new array

Tags: php, arrays

I have two arrays: `array1=(1,2,3,4)` and `array2=(1,2,5,6)`

I need to create `array3` which contain only those value which lie in `array2` not in `array1`. So my array3 will be `array3(5,6)`.

Comment: So, do you have any code that tries to do that? Otherwise, it'll be difficult to help you out.

Comment: Have you looked at [array_diff()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php) at all? The PHP manual is there for a reason.... telling us what we can do with PHP, and how to do it!

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8691329/php-how-to-compare-two-arrays-and-remove-duplicate-values

Comment: Didn't know SO now does people's work. Sorry about the rant but sometimes, people go too far to get some rep.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try using `array_diff()` like this:

```
<?php
$array1=array(1,2,3,4);
$array2=array(1,2,5,6);

print_r(array_diff($array2,$array1));// to reinitialize key use array_values().
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need the function `array_diff()`
http://php.net/array_diff

```
$a1 = array(0 => "a", 1 => "b", 2 => "c");
$a2 = array(3 => "c", 4 => "b", 5 => "d");
print_r(array_diff($a1,$a2));
//Array (
//  [0] => a
//)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it the below way

```
$array1=array (1,2,3,4);
$array2=array (1,2,5,6);
$result = array_diff ( $array1 , $array2);
echo "<pre>";print_r($result);exit;
```

This will output

```
Array
(
    [2] => 3
    [3] => 4
)
```

If you want to reindex array you can use below code

```
array_values($result);
```

Output:

```
Array
    (
        [0] => 3
        [1] => 4
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution:

```
<?php

$a = array(0=> 1, 1 => 23, 2 => 3);
$b = array(0=> 1, 1 => 23, 2 => 3, 3=> 5, 4=> 10);
$c = array_diff($b, $a);
var_dump($c);
?>
```

Output:

```
array (size=2)
  3 => int 5
  4 => int 10
```