# filter away duplicates in two lists not containing a dot php

Tags: php, arrays

Say that I have two arrays

**Array A**

```
N1099
N1100
N1100.1
N1100.2
N1100.3
N1100.4
N1100.5
N1101
N1101.1
```

**Array B**

```
N1100.1
N1100.2
N1100.3
N1100.4
N1100.5
N1100.6
N1101.1
```

Now You can see that array a contains N1100 and N1101 and they also has "children" in list B. Then I want to remove the parent in array A so that it becomes:

**Resulting Array after comparing the 2 arrays**

```
N1099
N1100.1
N1100.2
N1100.3
N1100.4
N1100.5
N1101.1
```

How can this be done in php?

I only found Questions like merge 2 arrays and filter duplicates and thats not really the case here. I want to filter away duplicates not containing a dot "." in it.

[PHP - How to compare two arrays and remove duplicate values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8691329/php-how-to-compare-two-arrays-and-remove-duplicate-values)

[PHP - Merging two array into one array (also Remove Duplicates)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13469803/php-merging-two-array-into-one-array-also-remove-duplicates)

Comment: It's not really clear what you're trying to do. And by lists do you mean arrays?

Comment: loop through the first array.  For each value, if it exists in the other array, keep it.  If it doesn't exist in the other array, it must be a parent and removed?  Not sure if that's how your data works, but that would be my approach.....EDIT oops, I see you want N1099 but not N1100.  I guess you'd have to split the strings (explode) and check the first half

Comment: `Now You can see that array a contains N1100 and 1001 and they also has "children" in list B.`. Where it is?

Comment: Sorry missspelled. Yes that would be a good Idea  RightClick thanks will try that. =)

Comment: @anders please up-vote the answer also

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do it in following manner:-

```
<?php

$listA = Array('N1099','N1100','N1100.1','N1100.2','N1100.3','N1100.4','N1100.5','N1101','N1101.1');
$listB = Array('N1100.1','N1100.2','N1100.3','N1100.4','N1100.5','N1100.6','N1101.1');
$listC = array();
$listA = array_unique($listA);
foreach($listA as $lisA){
    if(in_array($lisA,$listB) || !in_array($lisA.'.1',$listB)){
        $listC[] = $lisA;
    }
}
echo"<pre/>";print_r($listC);
?>
```

Output:-https://eval.in/379229