# Remove matched values from two arrays and display remaining values

Tags: php

I have two arrays:

```
$array1 = array(1,2,3,4);
$array2 = array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7);
```

How can I remove the matched values from the arrays and display the remaining values?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to compare two arrays and remove matching elements from one for the next loop?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/225371/how-to-compare-two-arrays-and-remove-matching-elements-from-one-for-the-next-loo?rq=1)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to compare two arrays and remove matching elements from one for the next loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/225371/how-to-compare-two-arrays-and-remove-matching-elements-from-one-for-the-next-loo)

Answer (score 0):

You should use [`array_diff`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php)

```
<?php
$array1 =array(1,2,3,4);
$array2 = array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7);
print_r(array_values(array_diff($array2,$array1)));
```

**`OUTPUT :`**

```
Array
(
    [0] => 5
    [1] => 6
    [2] => 7
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

You can use **array_diif()** function to get those values.

```
$A = array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7);
$B = array(1,2,3,4);

$C = array_intersect($A,$B);  //equals (1,2,3,4)
$D = array_diff($A,$B);       //equals (5,6,7)
```