# compare two arrays depending on the order

Tags: php, laravel

How can I compare two arrays depending on the order for ex. if array 1 is {1, 2 , 3}  and array 2 is {1,2,3} display true else for ex. array 2 {1,3,2} display false.. this is my code so far..

```
    foreach($questions as $question){

                  $question_answers = OrderingAnswer::where('question_id', $question->id)
                                    ->where('deleted',0)
                                    ->get()
                                    ->toArray();


                   $question_answer = $request->except('_token', 'test_id');

                   $answers = $question_answer[ $question->id];



                            foreach($question_answers as $answer){



                                if($answers === $question_answers ){


                                     echo  "true";
                                      }
                                      else{
                                     echo  "false";
                                      } 
                                }

              }
```

Comment: You mean do you want to compare based on keys or indexes?

Comment: You can take a look -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5678959/php-check-if-two-arrays-are-equal

Comment: I have "id" => 239 and I have the order like 239, 240 and I want that to compare

Comment: @ylli I think you should follow this link (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/225371/how-to-compare-two-arrays-and-remove-matching-elements-from-one-for-the-next-loo)

Answer (score 0):

```
you can refer this example:
<select name="tags" multiple required>
@foreach ($tags as $name)
@foreach($item->tags as $itemtag)
    @if($name == $itemtag->name)
        <option value="{{$name}}" selected>{{$name}}</option>
        <?php continue 2; ?>
    @endif
@endforeach
<option value="{{$name}}">{{$name}}</option>
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 0):

use [diff](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/collections#method-diff) available in collection

```
$collection = collect([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]);

$diff = $collection->diff([2, 4, 6, 8]);

$diff->all(); //it will return the non-common values present in the first array   [1, 3, 5]

$diff->isEmpty(); // it will return true if both array are common 
$diff->isNotEmpty(); // returns false if both array are common
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$arr1Collection1 = implode(', ', $array1);
$arr2Collection2 = implode(', ', $array2);

if($arr1Collection1 == $arr2Collection2){
echo true;
} else{
echo false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  $test1 = [1,2,3];
  $test2 = [1,3,2];

  if ($test1 === $test2) {
      echo "true";
  } else {
      echo "false";
  }
```